# How to pass prop to child component

Tags: react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I'm try to test a button component inside my component but I don't know how to pass the mockFn to the childComponent

I can get the ParentComponent with the shallow and then I find the child component but how I pass the mock funcion?

```
<ParentComponent>
    <ChildComponent onPress={this.myFunction}/>   
</ParentComponent>

const mockFunction = jest.fn();

describe("<ParentComponent> behaviour", () => {
 it("should call onSubmit", () => {
   const wrapper = shallow(<ParentComponent />);

   //How pass the mockFn here
   wrapper.find(ChildComponent).simulate('click');

   expect(mockFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

How I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should test this directly in the child component, like this:

```
const mockFunction = jest.fn();

describe("<ParentComponent> behaviour", () => {
    it("should call onSubmit", () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<ChildComponent onPress={mockFunction} />);
        wrapper.simulate('click');
        expect(mockFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ParentComponent
text = {'hey There'}>
    <ChildComponent 
alert(this.props.text)
onPress={this.myFunction}/>   
</ParentComponent>
```